# Block google from indexing some pages from site

Tags: indexing, robots.txt

I have a problem with lots of 404 errors on one site. I figured out that these errors are happening because google is trying to find pages that no longer exist.
Now I need to tell Google not to index those pages again.

I found some solutions on the internet about using robots.txt file. But this is not a site that I built. I just need to fix those errors.The thing is, those pages are generated. They do not physically exist in that form. So I can not add anything in php code.
And I am not quite sure how to add those to robot.txt.

When I just write:
***User-agent: *
noindex: /objekten/anzeigen/haus_antea/5-0000001575***

and hit test button in webmaster tools

I get this from Googlebot:
***Allowed
Detected as a directory; specific files may have different restrictions***

And I do not know what that means.

I am new in this kind of stuff so please write your answer as simpler as it can be.

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google will remove such pages that return a 404 error automatically from its index. Google will not display these pages in the results. So you don't need to care about that.

Just make sure, that these pages are not linked from other pages. If so, Google may try to index them from time to time. In this case you should return a 301 error (permanently moved) and redirect to the correct url. Google will follow the 301 errors and use the redirected url instead.

Robots.txt is only necessary, if you want to remove pages that are already in the search results. But I think pages with error code 404 will not be displayed there anyway.

Comment: Thing is page returns to manny 404 errors and it has bad raiting on google. I need to stop google for even looking for them. Sometimes before those existed but not anymore.

Comment: But why is google looking for these urls? Are they linked somewhere?

Comment: I can not tell. Thing it those are pages that existed once and some of them do still exist but on new url. Sometimes before they have been linked but as I know not any more. The thing is this is fully custom made cms with no existing documentation. I know very little about architecture of system. Only thing that I am sure about that google is crawling pages that used to exist but not any more.